# Configurar databases Relacional e Não-Relacional no mesmo projeto com Spring-Data + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mongodb, spring-data

Eu estou tentando criar uma aplicação Java onde eu preciso configurar dois bancos de dados: MongoDB e MySQL. Minha ideia é utilizar o Spring-Data com Hibernate para os dois bancos, mas encontrei apenas tutoriais para a configuração de Cross-Store entre os bancos.

Existe algum meio de eu configurar meus modelos para que cada um seja persistido no banco de dados que eu configurar no XML?

Comment: Já passei pela mesma dificuldade que você, no entanto meu caso era conectar em dois bancos relacionais diferentes (oracle e postgre) com suas cada qual com suas entidades. Pesquisei muito, mas não achei nada também. [Abri uma questão no SO em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926050/multiple-persistence-unit-in-persistence-xml-file-with-jpa-2-1) e não obtive resposta. Então tive que abandonar essa solução, mas ainda quer saber se isso é possível com Spring Data.

Comment: Acredito que isso é possível utilizando uma configuração parecida com essa https://gist.github.com/efraimcf/0af2cc68bfcdfbde55be

Li sobre algumas situações onde configuraram de forma diferente, como nessa thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877734/hibernate-using-two-different-database-schemas-in-the-same-application

Comment: Eu fiz essa configuração. Mas como você especificaria qual EM os DAOs do Spring Data usaria usando a configuração por XML?

Comment: No Hibernate ele já fica configurado pelo SessionFactory propriedade **packagesToScan** ... Com JPA, acredito que a resposta indicada pelo @utluiz abaixo seja a mais adequada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando configuração baseada em classes e anotações é possível dividir a configuração de cada repositório JPA do Spring Data e seu respectivo `DataSource` em um arquivo de configuração separado.

[Este artigo](http://scattercode.co.uk/2013/11/18/spring-data-multiple-databases/) tem um exemplo:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.bar" })
public class BarConfig {

    @Autowired JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("bardb").setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    ...

}
```

Depois se faria o mesmo para `FooConfig`, isto é, para a outra classe de configuração que vai definir outro `DataSource`, `EntityManager` e `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Via XML o processo seria idêntico. O importante é que o `EntityManager` e o `TransactionManager especificados em cada configuração de repositório apontem para o`DataSource` desejado.

Comment: Excelente @utluiz, vou fazer alguns testes aqui e volto a comentar. Obrigado!